# How to remove background of imported image in React Native?

Tags: react-native

How to get this effect in React Native?

Is it possible to get removing background effect in react-native?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I recommend to use react-native-drawpad and react-native-sketch-canvas.
It might give you hint. I am not sure it will be exact solution for this effect.